# Communication between windows/tabs with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, windows, cross-browser, communication

How can I have two tabs (or windows) that are on the same domain be able to talk to each other without having to have one window instance the other.

Comment: Some news about the topic:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19125823/how-is-it-possible-to-share-single-js-resource-between-browser-tabs/19165781#19165781
BNC Connector is still an option, a new option is intercom.js which uses localStorage, and another option is using shared webworkers.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way, I can make two flash movies on each page with LocalConnection to invoke JavaScript on the other page using externalinterface.

Put this in a AS3 swf, this is the receiver:

```
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;
import flash.net.LocalConnection;

var mLocalConnection:LocalConnection;
mLocalConnection = new LocalConnection();
mLocalConnection.connect("xivioview");
mLocalConnection.client=this;

function recieveText(textRecieved):void {
ExternalInterface.call(textRecieved);
};
```

And the sender swf:

```
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;
import flash.net.LocalConnection;

function sendtoview(con,val):String {
//create local connection for sending text
var sending_lc:LocalConnection;
sending_lc = new LocalConnection();
sending_lc.send("xivioview", "recieveText", val);
return "kk"
}
ExternalInterface.addCallback("sendtoview", sendtoview);
```

This is set up for one-way, and the javascript to use it:

```
document.getElementById("youembeddedobject").sendtoview("xivioview","alert('Hai!')")
```

That will execute that JavaScript code in the receiver's tab, but it won't execute until you go back to that tab (I already asked a question why, and have no response yet)

Comment: Any links about how you did this? Is this cross browser supported?

Comment: There's the source. It should work for every single browser, btw you can change the "xivioview" text, it's the connectionID.

Comment: The same holds for Silverlight. There is a LocalConnection object which enables to communicate locally between Silverlight controls across a local machine.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of would be to use XHR. Each window/tab communicates with the server, which in turn communicates back with other windows, pretty much the same way gmail chat works. Except that you would have 2 windows on the same client, rather than 1 window on 2 clients.

Answer (score 0):

I would just have a javascript execute in the page load that would continuously poll (window.setInterval) the sessionStore for a flag saying someone sent me a message then read that message from the sessionStore and then do whatever is required.

Answer (score 0):

Communicating between different JavaScript execution context was supported even before HTML5 if the documents was of the same origin. If not or you have no reference to the other `Window` object, then you could use the new **postMessage API** introduced with HTML5. I elaborated a bit on both approaches in this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18004937/1268003).