# How to make a clean transition while auto cycling webpages?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am currently trying to write web page that will display the current status of our continuous integration system. Let me preface this by saying that web development is **not** my area of expertise. We don't have any web developers here so I am going into all of this blind learning as I go. Please excuse my ignorance with regards to the current technologies out there for web development.

The main page shows the status of state of the current build. I have an html page with a jQuery script that is constantly refreshing the page and loading a php script that queries a MySQL db. The code I use is here,

```
<script src="./js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="./js/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
<script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#refreshpage").load("index.php");
        var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
            $("#refreshpage").load('index.php');
            }, 5000);
        refreshId = null;
        $("#refreshpage").unload();
    });
    </script>
<body class=bground>
    <center>
        <div id="refreshpage"></div>
    </center>
</body>
```

The page needs to be reloaded automatically so it will reflect the current status of the builds and with the current setup it works fantastically. I would like to extend this by adding additional pages that will relay other relevant information that a pull from a variety of sources. As this needs to be up to date I use that same code above we slight variations on for two more pages.

As each page needs to be refreshed in order to stay current with up to date information I decided on three separate and one page cycling through each one similiar to the techinique used here [How to auto refresh cycle multiple website page under one browser window like screen saver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4335702/how-to-auto-refresh-cycle-multiple-website-page-under-one-browser-window-like-sc) .
The code I use is this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    var sites = [
        "http://build/index.html",
        "http://proj1/next.html",
        "http://proj2/last.html"
    ];
    var activePage = sites.length;

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var $iframe = $("iframe").attr("src","http://build/index.html");
        setInterval(function() {
            (activePage == 0) ? activePage = sites.length -1 : activePage = currentSite -1;
                            $iframe.attr("src",sites[activePage]);
        }, 10000);
    });
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
    <iframe></iframe>
 </body>
```

This works fine except when ever it cycles to the next page it flashes to white. I know you can preload things on a single page but does anyone know the correct way when cycling though web pages so you don't see that jump?

Comment: I suspect this would be browser-dependent

Comment: One way is to use two alternating iframes and show the next one when it's done loading.

Comment: Rather than modifying the src on the same iframe you could create a new hidden iframe for each new page and wait a second after loading it with an interval, then remove the old iframe from the dom and show the new one.

Comment: @Maurice Perry It definitely was browser-dependent. For my situation as I have direct control over what is displaying the information it's an easy fix. I still am curious as to why it works in one and not the other(in my case it works in Firefox but not Chrome). Later I will try Jonathan and bhspencer 's suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't be better use a [FadeOut](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/) before overwrite de src and then a [fadeIn](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/)? Just saying.